I'm having difficulty install the R package devtools (R 3.6 in windows)
I need to use 3.6 version of R because of the availability of another package i need (LSTtools)
The error is "installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status"
i tried installing the package
> install.packages("devtools")

but it showed me this error
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:
  no fue posible abrir la URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES

A question box popped up asking if I wanted to attempt to install it from the sources, i clicked yes but it still didn't work, showing the error:
installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status


R version 3.6 is very old.  You shouldn't be using it unless you are very familiar with R, and know how to do by yourself the stuff it normally does automatically.  If there's a package that only works in 3.6 and not current versions, that's a sign that the package is not being properly maintained by its authors, and you shouldn't touch it with a 10 foot pole.

You could upgrade to the latest version of R, and then try installing LSTtools from Github: https://github.com/RichardLemoine/LSTtools

R is generally very conservative in its updates, and it should be generally fine to install a 4 year old package with R's latest version.

Try remotes::install_github('https://github.com/RichardLemoine/LSTtools', dependencies=TRUE), devtools is overrated.

remotes worked for me in R 3.6.1 on my Linux server.  I could not get devtools to install all afternoon.
